# Save multiple ndarray into each individual content of mat file - scipy

Tags: python, matlab, scipy

How can you save multiple `ndarray` into one `mat` file, using `scipy` function `savemat`? I wonder if I have two matrices call `A` and `B`, can I save them both to one `result.mat` like followed:

```
sio.savemat('result.mat', {'A':A})
sio.savemat('result.mat', {'B':B})
```

I did that and then open `result.mat` in MATLAB to only find the matrix `B`... `A` got overwrite. Any helps?

Comment: Each call is opening the file in a fresh `write` mode, replacing the previously created file.  This is normal Python file write practice.  But `savemat` accepts a file that is already open.  So open the file in write mode, and call `savemat` with that both times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [436]: with open('test.mat','wb') as f:  # need 'wb' in Python3
    savemat(f, {'A':np.arange(10)})
    savemat(f, {'B':np.ones((3,3))})
   .....:     

In [437]: loadmat('test.mat')
Out[437]: 
{'A': array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]),
 '__version__': '1.0',
 'B': array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.]]),
 '__globals__': [],
 '__header__': b'MATLAB 5.0 MAT-file Platform: posix, Created on: Fri May 13 16:38:04 2016'}
```